# Ensure WKWebView view has rendered content?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm experimenting with integrating a WKWebView in my app for some complex layout stuff. I don't want it to be pushed into my `UINavigationController` until the content inside has rendered (to save an ugly white flash). I tried just using `loadHTMLString`, but it doesn't seem to render immediately. I've even set up a JS event inside the WKWebView that uses a `WKScriptMessageHandler` to trigger the push but again, it fires too early.

Is there any way I can absolutely ensure that a WKWebView has rendered its content? `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't appear to have an effect. This doesn't happen with UIWebView, so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with WKWebView running out of process or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this delegate method to push the webview:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
 didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I'm trying to take a screenshot after the page is rendered, but this gets called (just?) before it is rendered. Dispatching 0.01s after this does work though(for a very simple website).